# npm run dev aborts on shared hosting sever

Tags: laravel, git, server, cpanel, laravel-mix

I'm trying to set up a git repository that contains a laravel project on a server that uses cpanel. After copy missing libraries and dependencias from both `composer.json` and `package.json` the project asks me to run `npm run dev` in order to create the mix manifest file. However, whenever I enter those commands this error keeps coming up:

```
> @ dev /home3/regioye5/repositorios/region-admin
> npm run development


> @ development /home3/regioye5/repositorios/region-admin
> mix

node[474]: ../src/node_platform.cc:61:std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start(): Assertion `(0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))' failed.
 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa0427e  [node]
 3: 0xa7429e  [node]
 4: 0xa74366 node::NodePlatform::NodePlatform(int, v8::TracingController*) [node]
 5: 0x9d1ae6 node::InitializeOncePerProcess(int, char**) [node]
 6: 0x9d1d21 node::Start(int, char**) [node]
 7: 0x7fbfeb70d555 __libc_start_main [/lib64/libc.so.6]
 8: 0x9694cc  [node]
Aborted
```

I've been looking for an answer on internet but nobody seems to have had this issue before. I rean in other posts that may be the job processes or something like that, I share to you the ulimited -a command result on server:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 800000
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 178728
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 800000
open files                      (-n) 100
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 15240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 25
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited laravel mix documentation and I found the following command. For me it worked like a charm!

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

It appears it goes straight to the library and asks it to config the file that contains the mix variables. Hope it works for you.

Comment: it says permission denied